# Comparing different fits (Quantile regression)

Tags: quantile-regression

I want to apply quantile regression (to calculate 2.5th percentile and 97.5th percentile). I was wondering which technique is more suitable for this variable vs age. I think Quantile LOESS fits better, But I am not sure, How can I know which method is better. Also since I have different analytes to analysis (*dependent variable* vs *age* *independent*). 
Also, I was wondering if I can apply the same technique to different variables? Or I need to compare the results of applying different techniques for each variable separately?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your analytical goal?

Comment: @ mkt, We have around 20 variables and we want to calculate the value of 2.5th percentile and 97.5th percentile of each variable by considering age as the continuous covariate/independent variable. We want to have age-specific percentile curves.

Comment: Not sure why but LOESS is way off compared to other models. This is a bit weird. And why to do univariate analysis? If you were interested in adjusting for confounders for age/response, why not to put them all and do penalized regression or something?

Comment: @user3119750, thanks for the reply. We calculate the reference interval for each analyte separately. It is easier for clinicians to understand the results.

Comment: But at some point, you have to do multivariate analysis no? It seems like you want to estimate some quantities rather than to predict, but either way, I think you will have to do some multivariate regression. And by the way, I still think it's odd that LOESS curve is way off compared to the others. I'm curious to find out why?

Comment: @ user3119750, thanks for the reply. I wanted to apply a multivariate model but my boss asked me to analyze each variable separately as he mentioned we want to calculate the reference interval for each variable separately. Yes, I am interested to estimate the quantiles rather than the prediction. So in this case, just comparing different fits visually would be enough or I need to calculate the residuals and AUC either?